# Preventing form elements from submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a use case that is odd in nature and I know there should be a better way to do this, but those issues aside is there a way to stop certain form elements from submitting?

My only thought would be to remove the 'unwanted' elements from the page in reaction to the Submit action, but I don't want them to actually be visibly removed to the end users.

Comment: Just curious: why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Just set the "disabled" property to `true` on the elements you don't want transmitted.  Do it in the "submit" handler or some other appropriate place.

Comment: @JeroenMoons one example is when there's some selector (like a set of radio buttons) that enables/disables parts of the form. The parts that are not "active" perhaps should not be posted.

Comment: Makes sense but in that case I would think the inactive parts can be hidden without scaring users (in this case they have selected something that makes other fields irrelevant and they are probably not surprised when these fields are removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could insert input fields with no "name" attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="empty-example" />
```

Or you could simply remove them once the form is submitted (in jquery):

```
$("form").submit(function() {

   $(this).children('#empty-example').remove();

});
```